# Combining SvelteKit with NodeJs and Express

Tags: node.js, express, adapter, svelte, sveltekit

I am completely new to SvelteKit (and development in general). I built several NodeJS apps with express to learn web development.

I now learned the basics of Svelte and SvelteKit (routing etc.), but I struggle to understand how I can use NodeJS code at the backend and SvelteKit at the frontend smoothly.

I understand that I need an adapter. But how can an express-app interact with the client without creating routings conflicts? How can I have backend data and algorythms, that I then send to the client directly or through SvelteKit?

Is there any resource I can read/watch to understand this?

Greetings from a Newbie

Comment: It is rather simple, you use fech or package axios to your svelte project, like with others js frameworks.

Comment: I don't want to run  NodeJS on a second machine. I want to have one codebase and be able to access NodeJS modules and share data between my NodeJS app and SvelteKit.

Comment: Now I don't understand. You dont need another machine to run node server and svelte server.  Svelte dev server tourns on port 5000 and you can to define your node server on port 8000 always on your own one machine. You fech yorus data from node app to svelte like API.

Comment: [here](https://youtu.be/RpMBkkcxnMo) you have a little tutoral

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks!